# In which ragams do Ganesh and Kumaresh play kalpana swarams for the pallavi in *Shantham*?

Tags: instrumental, cd, raga, indian-classical

The Carnatic violin duo [Ganesh and Kumaresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesh_and_Kumaresh) released a 2-disc album titled *Shantham* in 2002, Shruthilaya Audio Recording.

The first track of disc 2 is a *pallavi* ("Un tiruvadi en gati") in the ragam [*Sankarabharanam*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dheerashankarabharanam) set to [*Adi talam*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adi_tala). They play [*kalpana swarams*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalpanaswaram) in numerous ragams from (approximately) 10:15--14:30 mins. I'm interested in knowing which ragams they play the *kalpana swarams* in, and was hoping someone here could help me out.

---

The entire album is available [here](https://music.amazon.in/albums/B002NNSBTE?ref=dm_sh_94f2-a249-dmcp-745d-97277&musicTerritory=IN&marketplaceId=A21TJRUUN4KGV) on Amazon Music, but one has to sign up to listen to it.

Comment: Actually, after clicking the amazon link, it appears that it is needed to create an account and I don't plan to do it. Please read [this](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328/should-we-restrict-hosting-services-we-allow-for-id-questions), I agree your question is not about ID, but it seems the community prefers not having to create accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ganesh and Kumaresh play kalpana swarams in Sankarābharanam from 6:26 to 10:17 mins. The ragamalika swarams begin from the 10:17 mark, and follow a clear progression.

The ragamalika swarams are played in 24 different ragams, in sets of 6. The first six are played for 2 *āvarthanams* (cycles of the *tala*) each, the next six for 1 *āvarthanam* each, the next six for 1/2 *āvarthanam* each and the last six for 1/4 *āvarthanam* each. So, the length of time is halved as they progress from one set of six ragams to the next.

Between each set of six ragamalika swarams, Sankarābharanam is played for the appropriate length of time as follows: in the first interlude, it is played for 1 *āvarthanam*, in the second for 1/2 *āvarthanam* and in the third for 1/4 *avarthanam*. So, Sankarābharanam is played for as long as each of the ragams in the following set will be played.

Ganesh and Kumaresh also play one after the other, so if a ragam is played for 2 *āvarthanams*, then each of them play it for 1 *āvarthanam*. If a ragam is played for 1 *āvarthanam*, then each of them play it for 1/2 *āvarthanam*. And so on.

Now for the individual ragams themselves:

**First set:**

1. Kānadā (10:17)
2. Pantuvarāli (10:37)
3. Nāttaikurinji (10:58)
4. Ānandabhairavi (11:19)
5. Hamsānandi (11:41)
6. Kalyānavasantam (12:02)

**Interlude:** Sankarābharanam (12:23)

**Second set:**

7. Shubhapantuvarāli (12:34)
8. Mohanakalyāni (12:44)
9. Janaranjani (12:54)
10. Vasantā (13:04)
11. Nāsikabhushani (13:15)
12. Ranjani (13:25)

**Interlude:** Sankarābharanam (13:35)

**Third set:**

13. Durbār (13:41)
14. Valaji (13:46)
15. Kuntalavarāli (13:51)
16. Bilahari (13:56)
17. Sri Ranjani (14:01)
18. Lalitā (14:06)

**Interlude:** Sankarābharanam (14:11)

**Fourth set:**

19. Chandrakauns (14:14)
20. Sunādavinodini (14:17)
21. Amritavarshini (14:19)
22. Hindolam (14:22)
23. Mohanam (14:25)
24. Hamsanādam (14:28)

*Main ragam resumed:* Sankarābharanam from 14:30 onwards.